# Why is this request returning a 400? (Python3 requests)

Tags: python, http, python-requests, discord, http-status-codes

I am having trouble with sending a post request as it return an error 400 rather than the expected 204, despite the fact that sending a similar request in the same style seems to work fine for other parts of the same site.

Here is an example of an accepted request from google chrome:

```
Request URL: https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 204 
Remote Address: IP
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Track, X-Super-Properties, X-Context-Properties, X-Failed-Requests, X-Fingerprint, X-RPC-Proxy, X-Debug-Options, If-None-Match
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: https://discordapp.com
alt-svc: clear
cf-ray: 4ae0db43cf473464-LHR
date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 09:20:28 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
status: 204
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
via: 1.1 google
:authority: discordapp.com
:method: POST
:path: /api/v6/users/@me/relationships
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB
authorization: USER TOKEN
content-length: 46
content-type: application/json
cookie: __cfduid=dda2a2e2ad66d52129871a4410708b3941545858349; _ga=GA1.2.393621366.1545937419; locale=en-US; _gid=GA1.2.803863711.1550442266; _gat_UA-53577205-2=1
dnt: 1
origin: https://discordapp.com
referer: https://discordapp.com/channels/@me
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
x-context-properties: eyJsb2NhdGlvbiI6IkFkZCBGcmllbmQifQ==
x-fingerprint: 547382949931384833.wx3cZudz6zpRaSSwwn2N0xyAmAo
{username: "USERNAME", discriminator: 999}
discriminator: 9999
username: "USERNAME"
```

And here is my code to try and send the request:

```
headers={"authorization": "TOKEN HERE"}
params={"username": "USERNAME", "discriminator": 9999}

r = requests.post("https://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/relationships",headers=headers,params=params)
print(r.status_code)
```

I have previously had a similarly structure request for deleting chat messages that worked correctly:

```
requests.delete("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + CHANNEL ID + "/messages/" + MESSAGE ID, headers={"authorization": "TOKEN"})
```

Comment: That is a 204 response identical to what you posted. The only difference being the TOKEN

Comment: the authorization, username and discriminator fields are all substituted for privacy reasons.

Comment: Oh yeah. The domain is different also. Your not working example has canary in it.

Comment: That's my bad, it's the beta testing site and what you're meant to use when interacting with the api, it doesn't affect the request at all.

Comment: Well since it appears to have worked before. Surely something on the server has changed.

Comment: No, changing the domain makes no difference and the delete request still functions correctly, it's a 400 which specifically means something about the structure of my request is bad.

Comment: Yeah but the POST request you posted above DOES give you a 204. Hence it did work.

Comment: Yes but if you read the post that's one sent from chrome that does function, I'm attempting to replicate the request within python which is returning an error 400.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you mean. I'd ask on their help support forum. Their docs do state `The Discord Store is still in a beta period. All documentation and functionality can and will change.`

Comment: That's just for the store, I will check the docs though.

Answer (score 0):

Params must be passed in as json format:

```py
r = requests.post("https://discordapp.com/api/v9/users/@me/relationships",headers=headers,json=params)
```